# MERN App works fine on dev but not on production

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mern

I'm having this error with my react app that I'm finding very difficult to debug. I created this app with the mern stack and it works perfectly on my local server, fetching all the needed data from my mongo db database and displaying, but when I published it on heroku, I get this error :

> "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: this.state.data.map is not a function".

Now, I logged `this.state.data` and it outputs on dev, but on production, it doesn't work. Here is the url https://desolate-brushlands-16337.herokuapp.com

and please see my react code below. I will really appreciate any info. Thanks

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import moment from 'moment';

import $ from 'jquery';
import axios from 'axios';

import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

import blogTopImage from '../../images/blog2.png';


var divStyle;

divStyle = {
  backgroundImage: "url("  + blogTopImage + ")" ,
  backgroundPosition: 'center center',
  backgroundRepeat: 'no-repeat',            
  backgroundSize: 'contain',
  height: '300px',
}


class Blog extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super()

    this.state = {
      data :[],
      firstName:'',
      lastName:'',
      email:'',
    }
    this.handleFirstNameChange = this.handleFirstNameChange.bind(this);
    this.handleLastNameChange = this.handleLastNameChange.bind(this);
    this.handleEmailChange = this.handleEmailChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleFirstNameChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({firstName:e.target.value})
  }

  handleLastNameChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({lastName:e.target.value})
  }

  handleEmailChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({email:e.target.value})
  }

  enter = (e) => {

    axios.post('../api/newsletter', {
      firstName: this.state.firstName,
      lastName: this.state.lastName,
      email: this.state.email,

    })
    .then(function (response) {
      console.log('response from add post is ', response);

    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
    });

  }

  componentDidMount = () =>{

    axios.get(`../api/check`)
    .then(res => {
      var data = res.data;
        this.setState({ data });
    })
    
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('.container').fadeIn(3000);
    });
  
  }

  render() {

    return (

<main>
  <div class="wik31">
    <div style={divStyle} >

    </div>
  </div>

  <div className="container">
    <div className="space6"></div>
    <div className=" row">

      {this.state.data.map(data => 
        <Link to={'/page/' + data._id}>
          <div className=" bog col s12 m6 l4 blog-container" style= {{
            backgroundImage: "url(" + data.postImage + ")" ,
            backgroundPosition: "center center",
            backgroundRepeat: "no-repeat",
            backgroundSize: "cover",
            height: '350px',
          }}>


            <div className="after" >
              <div className="blog_title">
                <p class="wik28"> {data.title}</p>
              </div>
              <div className="blog_date">
                <p> 
                  {moment(data.timestamp).format('ll')}
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>

          </div>
        </Link>
  
      )}

    </div>

    <div className="space2"></div>

    <form>
      <h4 className="wik7  center">Sign up for The Peel</h4>
      <div className="space6"></div>

      <div id="notif-container">

        <div className="input-field  notif-item1">
          <input type="text" id="inputFirstName"  onChange= 
            {this.handleFirstNameChange.bind(this)} placeholder="First 
            Name" required className="validate  tat"/>
        </div>

        <div className="input-field  notif-item1">
          <input type="text" id="inputLastName"  onChange= 
            {this.handleLastNameChange.bind(this)} placeholder="Last 
            Name" required className="validate  tat"/>
        </div>

        <div className="input-field notif-item2">
          <input type="text" id="inputEmail"  onChange= 
            {this.handleEmailChange.bind(this)} placeholder="Email" 
            required className="validate  tat"/>
        </div>

        <div className="notif-item3">
          <button className="btn btn-large 
            BottonColor"onClick={this.enter.bind(this)}  type="submit" 
            style = {{width:'100%'}}>
              subscribe
          </button>
        </div>
      
      </div>
    </form>

    <div className="space2b"></div>

  </div>
  <div className="space5"></div>
</main>

    );
  }

}

export default Blog;
```

Comment: Where is your MongoDB database?

Comment: Also, where is the `api` file you're using?

Comment: my mongodb database is on mlab.com. i'm using express/node js.